# How can I set hostname as chinese?

Tags: hostname, chinese

The hostname of machine is english , but our workmates need chinese,some of them couldn't recongnize english.  So, how can i do it ??

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use Chinese characters in the hostname. Here is an extract from the `hostname` [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hostname.7.html):

> Each element of the hostname must be from 1 to 63 characters long and
>   the entire hostname, including the dots, can be at most 253 characters
>   long.  Valid characters for hostnames are ASCII(7) letters from a to
>   z, the digits from 0 to 9, and the hyphen (-).  A hostname may not
>   start with a hyphen.

But if your workmates are familiar with Arabic numerals, you may chose a hostname with a single letter between **a** and **z**, then numbering the machines.

For instance `m001`, `m002`, `m003`, ...

Comment: Thank you very much. It is helpful .Thanks again.